# Dynamic Pivot rows to Columns-SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to dynamically generate pivot based on columns from the table.

Here is sample data which looks something like this.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgZ6p.png)

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +--------+----------------------+--------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------+ |
| | Sr No  |    Invoice Date    |  Invoice No  |            Payer Name            |  IGMNo  | Container No | Size | Type | CHACode | CHAName |    Act Gatein Date    | Container Agent |    Container  Agent  Name    |    Importer Name    |        Activity Description        | Amount |          |
| +--------+----------------------+--------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------+ |
| |    1 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Contrainer Ground Rent Charges        |    650 |          |
| |    2 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Fuel Charges                            |    850 |        |
| |    3 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Handling and  PNR Movement Charges    |   7400 |          |
| |    4 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Weighment Charges                    |    200 |           |
| |    5 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Movement and Increase Charges |   1800 |        |
| |    6 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Documentation Charges                |    250 |           |
| |    7 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Fuel Charges                            |    850 |        |
| |    8 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Handling and  PNR Movement Charges    |   7400 |          |
| |    9 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Insurance Charges                    |    300 |           |
| |    10 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Weighment Charges                    |    200 |          |
| |    11 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Movement and Increase Charges |   1800 |       |
| |    12 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Tracking Charges            |    100 |         |
| |    13 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Documentation Charges                |    250 |          |
| |    14 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Seal Charges                            |    0 |         |
| |    15 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Tracking Charges            |    100 |         |
| |    16 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1699560  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Seal Charges                            |    0 |         |
| |    17 | 7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM | MII180700001 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | DFSU1696812  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Insurance Charges                    |    300 |          |
| |    18 | 7-1-2018 12:50:13 AM | MII180700002 | TAEWOONG LOGISTICS PVT LTD    | 2198466 | CNSU2012015  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 7:40:06 AM  | AABCH5572J    | HYUNDAI MERCHANT MARINE LINE | TAEWOONGLOGISTICSPVTL | Container Tracking Charges            |    100 |           |
| |    19 | 7-1-2018 12:50:13 AM | MII180700002 | TAEWOONG LOGISTICS PVT LTD    | 2198466 | CNSU2012015  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 7:40:06 AM  | AABCH5572J    | HYUNDAI MERCHANT MARINE LINE | TAEWOONGLOGISTICSPVTL | Seal Charges                            |    0 |           |
| |    20 | 7-1-2018 12:50:13 AM | MII180700002 | TAEWOONG LOGISTICS PVT LTD    | 2198466 | CNSU2012015  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 7:40:06 AM  | AABCH5572J    | HYUNDAI MERCHANT MARINE LINE | TAEWOONGLOGISTICSPVTL | Value Added Charges                    |   1000 |          |
| |    21 | 7-1-2018 12:50:13 AM | MII180700002 | TAEWOONG LOGISTICS PVT LTD    | 2198466 | CNSU2012015  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 7:40:06 AM  | AABCH5572J    | HYUNDAI MERCHANT MARINE LINE | TAEWOONGLOGISTICSPVTL | Handling and  PNR Movement Charges    |   6850 |           |
| |    22 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | FCIU4016495  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 11:35:29 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Movement and Increase Charges |   1800 |       |
| |    23 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | FCIU4016495  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 11:35:29 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Fuel Charges                            |    850 |       |
| |    24 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | FCIU4016495  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 11:35:29 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Insurance Charges                    |    300 |          |
| |    25 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | TEMU5684719  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 1:00:46 AM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Movement and Increase Charges |   1800 |       |
| |    26 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | TEMU5684719  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 1:00:46 AM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Container Tracking Charges            |    100 |         |
| |    27 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | TEMU5684719  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 1:00:46 AM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Handling and  PNR Movement Charges    |   7400 |         |
| |    28 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | TEMU5684719  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 1:00:46 AM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Insurance Charges                    |    300 |          |
| |    29 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | TEMU5684719  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 1:00:46 AM  | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Seal Charges                            |    0 |         |
| |    30 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | FCIU4016495  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 11:35:29 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Documentation Charges                |    250 |          |
| |    31 | 7-1-2018 1:55:51 AM  | MII180700003 | PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED | 2198105 | FCIU4016495  |   20 | GB   |        |        | 6-29-2018 11:35:29 AM | AACCT8966D    | T S LINES AGENCY            | PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT | Handling and  PNR Movement Charges    |   7400 |         |
| +--------+----------------------+--------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to pivot **activity description** columns which can be added dynamically into my FCL_Parent table.

So In order to get values dynamically from that column, I used below code,

```
 DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
 SET @Columns = (SELECT DISTINCT Quotename([Activity Description]) + ',' 
             FROM  [dbo].[FCLParent]  
             FOR xml path('')) 
 SET @Columns = LEFT (@Columns, Len(@Columns) - 1)
```

Below is my requirement,

**I need distinct container number, with the activity description as pivot columns and amount column as values in pivot and my other required columns too.**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Q6e.png)

In order to achieve this I used below code,

```
  SET @sql = 'select [Payer Name],[Container No],[Size],[Type],
  [CHAName],[Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name],[Importer Name],'         + @Columns 
   + 'FROM [dbo].[FCLParent]
   pivot (max([Amount]) for [Activity Description] in (' 
       + @Columns + '))pv' 
   EXEC(@sql)
```

I am not getting the expected pivot columns. some values are missing in it. Ex. Some charges available are missing in the pivot. I'm also not sure whether the query is right or wrong.

Thanks

Comment: add your sample data along with your expected result

Comment: I always felt, with queries of this nature where the pivot columns change continuously, that the pivot is the wrong way round - columns should be relatively fixed/unchanging, and rows present the variation.. Database 101

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, both the columns in original table will keep changing. But, my columns will also be added with appropriate pivot values too...

Comment: Hi @Sreenu131, I added data and output in the link, FYI I need to pivot activity description column in my data. Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: @krishna31 Hi ,it seems that pivot code you have written is correct but may i am not sure that code will satisfies your requirement. But Can i have Your source data table Sql server script with limited lines of crate and insert script ,so that i could try.i am not able generate insert script by seeing images

Comment: Hi, it produces the output of all columns, but I need only distinct of container no. so I used my code as 'SET sql = 'select [Container No],[Payer Name],[Size],[Type],
            [CHAName],[Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name],[Importer Name],' + Columns 
           + ' 
  FROM [dbo].[FCLParent] Group by [Container No]

 pivot (max([Amount]) for [Activity Description] in (' 
           + Columns + '))pv' ', But it throws an error as incorrect syntax near keyword Pivot. Let me know how to correct.

Comment: Hi @Sreenu131, I have added to it, please let me know if you can support on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI Try this dynamic sql which have wriiten based on your sample data .I may guess this code will helps you for sure
Below is sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempData')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempData
;WITH CTE(SrNo  ,    InvoiceDate    ,  InvoiceNo  ,            PayerName            ,  IGMNo  , ContainerNo , Size , [Type] , CHACode , CHAName ,    ActGateinDate    , ContainerAgent ,    ContainerAgentName    ,    ImporterName    ,        ActivityDescription        , Amount          )
AS
(
SELECT 1 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM'  , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Contrainer Ground Rent Charges'   , 650      UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM'  , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Fuel Charges'                            , 850    UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM'  , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Handling and  PNR Movement Charges'    ,7400      UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM'  , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Weighment Charges'                    ,200       UNION ALL 
SELECT 5 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Container Movement and Increase Charges' ,1800    UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Documentation Charges'                ,250       UNION ALL 
SELECT 7 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Fuel Charges'                           ,850     UNION ALL
SELECT 8 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Handling and  PNR Movement Charges'    ,7400      UNION ALL 
SELECT 9 ,  '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Insurance Charges'                    ,300       UNION ALL 
SELECT 10 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Weighment Charges'                    ,200       UNION ALL
SELECT 11 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM' ,  'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Container Movement and Increase Charges',1800    UNION ALL
SELECT 12 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM' ,  'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Container Tracking Charges'            ,100      UNION ALL
SELECT 13 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM' ,  'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Documentation Charges'                ,250       UNION ALL
SELECT 14 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM' ,  'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Seal Charges'                            ,0      UNION ALL
SELECT 15 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Container Tracking Charges'            ,100      UNION ALL
SELECT 16 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1699560' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-29-2018 12:10:52 AM' , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Seal Charges'                          ,0      UNION ALL
SELECT 17 , '7-1-2018 12:42:56 AM' , 'MII180700001' , 'PROMEDIA TRADING PRIVATE LIMITED' , 2198105 , 'DFSU1696812' ,   20 , 'GB'   ,NULL  ,NULL , '6-28-2018 9:32:02 PM'  , 'AACCT8966D'    , 'T S LINES AGENCY'  , 'PROMEDIATRADINGPRIVAT' , 'Insurance Charges'                    ,300       
)
SELECT * INTO #TempData FROM CTE
```

Sql Script

```
    DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) ='',
            @Columns2 VARCHAR(MAX) ='',
            @Sql nvarchar (max)=''

    SELECT @Columns=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',',+ QUOTENAME([ActivityDescription] )
                    FROM  #TempData FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

    SELECT @Columns
    SELECT @Columns2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',',+ 'MAX('+QUOTENAME([ActivityDescription] ) +') AS '+QUOTENAME([ActivityDescription] )
                    FROM  #TempData FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

    SET @sql = 'SELECT  [PayerName],
                        [ContainerNo],
                        [Size],
                        [Type],
                        [CHAName],
                        [ActGateinDate], 
                        [ContainerAgentName],
                        [ImporterName],'+ @Columns2+
                'FROM
                (SELECT * FROM  #TempData) AS Src
                PIVOT(MAX([Amount]) FOR [ActivityDescription] IN ('+ @Columns +')
                )pv  
                GROUP BY [PayerName],[ContainerNo],[Size],[Type],
                        [CHAName],[ActGateinDate], [ContainerAgentName],
                        [ImporterName]'

    PRINT(@sql)
    EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with your above code, but received error as invalid syntax near pivot. with following code, SET sql = 'select [Container No],[Payer Name],[Size],[Type],
            [CHAName],[Act Gatein Date], [Container  Agent  Name],[Importer Name],' + Columns 
           + '
  FROM [dbo].[FCLParent]  Group by [Container No] 
 pivot (max([Amount]) for [Activity Description] in (' 
           + Columns + ')' 

EXEC(sql).Can you correct me on this, While using groupby this error occurs.

Comment: It throws invalid syntax near AS